# App Engine Server Side error notification

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to know how I can get Google App Engine to notify me via email the moment a 500 is registered on the server.

My app is running Flask, Python on Google App Engine.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on [ereporter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/recording_exceptions_with_ereporter). It's allows you to configure a cron job wich will send you an email with latest registered exceptions.

**UPDATE**:
For WSGI in app.yaml you should use:

```
- url: /_ereporter.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.ereporter.report_generator.application
  login: admin
```

Comment: I get an exception google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/ereporter/report_generator.py

Comment: You should use WSGI https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/migrate27#wsgi